# unassigned local variable - wrong set up of class?

Tags: c#

I hope someone can explain why I receive this message related in my code below. Later on I want the user of the application to choose which animal to be and then to set a name, by using `console.readline`. But before I implemented this I wanted to set up the classes and just test the print function.

> Error message: "Use of unasigned local variable "rocky"

```
namespace GameApp
{
    class Program
    {
        //base class
        class Animal
        {

            public string name;
            public int age;
            public int health;

            public void PrintInfo()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
                Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
                Console.WriteLine("Health: " + health);
            }
        }
        //tiger class
        class Tiger : Animal
        {
            public Tiger()
            {
                age = 22;
                health = 8;
                name = "input fom player";
            }


        }
        //lion class
        class Lion : Animal
        {

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //test the print function
            Tiger rocky = new Tiger()
            {
                rocky.PrintInfo();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to use an instance inside its object initializer. Try this instead: `Tiger rocky = new Tiger(); rocky.PrintInfo();`

Comment: Are the nested classes (`Animal` inside `Program`) intentional? If not I suggest not having them as nested to begin with. Use nested classes only when necessary.

Comment: Perfect Sebastian, it worked now! Thanks for the suggestion Sach, I will follow your advice.

Comment: Something else to consider would be to override the `ToString()` method on your `Animal` class: `public override string ToString() { return $"Name: {name}, Age: {age}, Health: {health}"; }` Then instead of `rocky.PrintInfo()` you would do `Console.WriteLine(rocky);`. It's often better for classe methods to return a string, and leave the console writing to the client application.

Comment: You should also use public properties rather than public fields for your class, and they should be PascalCase: `public string n=Name { get; set; }  public int Age { get; set; }  public int Health { get; set; }`

Comment: Then you can also set the `Name` property in the object initializer: `Tiger rocky = new Tiger() { Name = "Rocky" };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for [Object Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible **fields or properties** of an object at creation time without having to invoke a constructor followed by lines of assignment statements.

You cannot call methods from inside an object initializer.

Try changing this:

```
Tiger rocky = new Tiger()
{
    rocky.PrintInfo();
}
```

To this:

```
Tiger rocky = new Tiger();
rocky.PrintInfo();
```